# VBA HTML scrape. Working with dynamic webpage and am unable to indicate the specific data point needed

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm working with the website below

https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/university-of-virginia

My goal is to pull the information pertaining to the cost of the school. I was able to pull the costs for In-State students using a code similar to that below.

```
Select "Paying" tab  
Set Paying = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(97)  
Paying.Click

Set ISOCTF = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)  
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = ISOCTF.innerText
```

Yet when I try to pull "Out-of-State" costs, I am unable to select the Out-of-State Costs tab. I inspected the HTML script and it indicates that a line needs to be activated before I am capable of retrieving the information needed. How do I go about activating the "Out-Of-State Costs" tab?

Any insight into this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you get the Out-of-State tab by its `id`:

```
Set OutOfStateTab = ie.document.getElementById("cpProfile_tabs_paying_outstatecosts_anchor")
```

Then, you get the only link (`a`) child of this object and fire the `click()` method in order to select:

```
OutOfStateTab.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

I'd suggest you to wait a bit before starting to scrape, as a link navigation would take the server few milliseconds to load:

```
While ie.Busy
Loop
```

Comment: @J.Nag695 if it worked, please mark the answer so your question will get closed.